# Custom content on a tags page

Tags: hakyll

I have setup Hakyll to generate basic tag pages from blog posts as follows:

```
main = do    
    hakyll $ do

        match "preambles/*.md" $ compile $ pandocCompiler >>= relativizeUrls

        tags <- buildTags "posts/*.md" (fromCapture "tags/*.html")

        tagsRules tags $ \tag pattern -> do
            let title = "Posts tagged \"" ++ tag ++ "\""
            route idRoute
            compile $ do
                posts <- recentFirst =<< loadAll pattern
                preamble <- loadBody $ fromFilePath ("preambles/" ++ tag ++ ".html")
                let ctx = constField "title" title
                        `mappend` listField "posts" postCtx (return posts)
                        `mappend` bodyField preamble
                        `mappend` defaultContext

                makeItem ""
                    >>= loadAndApplyTemplate "templates/tag.html" ctx
                    >>= loadAndApplyTemplate "templates/default.html" ctx
                    >>= relativizeUrls
...
```

I would like to be able to supply an optional preamble for each page.

To do this I would expect to have a markdown file per tag in a *preambles* directory, and attempt to use these when building the tags pages. However, I can't figure out how to make this optional, because `loadSnapshot` will `fail` if not found.

Is this an appropriate approach, and if so, how would I handle missing data?

Also, I'm not sure that `bodyField` is the appropriate way to pass the data to the template.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an entirely reasonable approach to me.

To answer your main question, you can take advantage of the [`Alternative`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Alternative) instance on `Compiler` to provide a fallback.

I'd like to suggest a few minor changes too.

---

First off, replace your preamble rule with:

```hs
let preamblePattern = "preambles/*.md"
match preamblePattern $ do
    compile $ pandocCompiler 
                 >>= relativizeUrls
                 >>= saveSnapshot "preamble"
                 >>= pure . void
```

`>>= pure . void` converts the `Compiler (Item String)` into a `Compiler (Item ())`.
This prevents Hakyll from producing any output files for this rule.
The `saveSnapshot "preamble"` means we can still get at the content later.

In addition to this, I've extracted the pattern into a variable, for reasons that will become clear later.

---

Then, replace:

```hs
preamble <- loadBody $ fromFilePath ("preambles/" ++ tag ++ ".html")
```

with:

```hs
let preambleIdent = fromCapture preamblePattern tag
preamble <- (loadSnapshotBody preambleIdent "preamble") <|> pure "fallback"
```

This uses [`fromCapture`](https://jaspervdj.be/hakyll/reference/Hakyll-Core-Identifier-Pattern.html#v:fromCapture), to generate the identifier from the Pattern.
This reduces duplication, and also sidesteps the bug in your code where you used the extension `".html"` when the `Identifier` is generated from the original filepath, and has extension `".md"`.

This uses `loadSnapshotBody` rather than `loadBody` because of the change suggested above, where we remove the content from the rule output.

Most importantly, it uses `<|>` from `Alternative` to provide a fallback.
You'll probably want to replace `"fallback"` with whichever default value you want.

---

Finally, `makeItem ""` needs to be replaced with `makeItem preamble`.

Comment: I realize I'm digging up a relatively old post here; I recently ran into a very similar problem on my own blog